# Subscriber onNext is called before completion of the asynchronous requests in rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, dagger-2, android-mvp

I have implemented a repository pattern in MVP using RxJava2

**RemoteDataSource.java**

```
public Observable<List<A>> getAList(){
          return ApiService.
                getAList()
                .compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers())
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Timber.d(..))
                .doOnError(throwable -> Timber.d(..))
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    Timber.d(..);
                });
      }
```

**LocalDataSource.java**

```
public Observable<List<A>> getAList(){
    return mDbHelper .....from SQLBrite..
}

public void saveAList(List<<A> a){
    SQlBriteTransaction...
}
```

**Repository.java**  (Update)

```
  @Inject
  public Repository(DownloadUtils downloadUtils){
   this.mDownloadUtils = downloadUtils;
   }

   @Override
   public Observable<List<A>> getAList(){
     return  mRemoteDataSource
            .getAList()
             .flatMapIterable(List<A> -> a)
            .flatMap(A a ->
      ************************************************************   
               return Observable.fromIterable(a.getB())
                     .flatMap((Function<B, ObservableSource<B>>) b ->
                                       Observable.create(emitter -> 
                                                emitter.onNext(new 
            DownloadUtils().downloadFiles(b,totalListCount,emitter))))
                                .toList()
                                .toObservable()

     ***************************************************
                    .toList()
                    .toObservable()
                    .doOnNext( List<A>  a -> {

     --------------Only the first change in B value is inserted in Db-
                       mLocalDataSource.saveAList(a);
                    });
    }
```

**DownLoadUtils.java** (Update)

```
void downloadBFiles(B b, int totalCount,ObservableEmitter<B> emitter){
        fileCount = b.size;
         b.get(index).setDataToChange(dataToChange);

         *** I am using PR Downloader for aynchronous download using 
            RECURSION **
        PRDownloader.download(remoteUrl, filePath, fileName)
                .build()
        .setOnStartOrResumeListener(() -> {
            })
            .setOnProgressListener(progress -> {
                int progressPercent = (int) (progress.currentBytes * 
                   100 / progress.totalBytes);,

             })
            .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadComplete() {
  ********************* emitter.onComplete() ******************


             @Override
                public void onError(Error error) {
                  }   
     }
```

**Presenter.java**

```
void getVideosFromRepo(){

    disposable = mRepository
                 .getAList()
                 .doOnSubscribe(d _-> "Started Loading")
                 .subscribe(
                   //OnNext
    ------------- Here the OnNext is being called before Asynchronous Operation completes!!-------

                    List<A> a -> mView.setAList(a);
                   )


}
```

Above presenter implementation, returns the List in the *onNext* of the *Presenter* even before asynchronous download completes... what changes are needed , so that onNext(subscribe) is called after all the download Has *Completed*.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using asynchronous services **outside** of the RxJava observer chain, so RxJava has no way to manage the data being passed. Since `downloadBFiles()` uses a separate observer chain, you have lost the thread, so to speak.

Rather than using `doOnNext()` to trigger the download, you will need to use `flatMap()` so that the download result is included in your observer chain.

Comment: ..hi.if i replace **doOnNext** with **flatMap** would i be able to return the value of **a with changes in b**..can you please show the change in code that needs to be done!

Comment: hi..i tried using the **flatMap** and i still get the same result...!! instead of **doOnNext** i used **.flatMap((Function<List<B>, ObservableSource<List<B>>>) List<B> b ->
                                    Observable.fromCallable(() ->
                                            mDownloadUtils.downloadFiles(b,0)))..map(b -> {
                                a.setB(b);
                                return a;
                            }))**

Comment: Is `downloadFiles()` still using a separate "PR Downloader", whatever that is? If so, the `flatMap()` won't help, as it won't wait for the download to complete.

Comment: ...yes it is using a separate downloader!!...is there any work around for this !!

Comment: You can create an observable that wraps the separate downloader. Use `Observable.create()` and have your download listener emit the value. Without knowing how you invoke your downloader, I cannot show you sample code.

Comment: hi..i have updated the **Repository .java ** and **DownloadUtils** ..now the problem is that the Asynchrnous task is never getting completed...but **subscribe(onNext)** waits for the obsevable to complete!!!